# Removing first and last character of a big file via terminal

Tags: linux, file

I have several big files (ranging from 1GB to 1TB) and I want to remove the first and last character in each.

What's a **fast** way to do it (preferably with a simple bash script)? I don't need to save the old file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fast way to do it in a shell.

```
head -c -1 < in.txt | tail -c +1 > out.txt
```

If you don't mind dropping to C, calling `sendfile(2)` with a `*offset` of 1 and a `count` of the size less 2 will likely be the fastest possible way.

Comment: You mean +1 on `tail` there :)

Comment: I'm getting "invalid byte count" by doing this, mine is a json file if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

To quickly truncate the **last** character of a file you can use:
`truncate -s-1 file`  This will modify the file directly and avoid creating a copy of your large file.  This asks truncate to reduce the size of the file by 1 .  See original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568723