# How can I remove the last character of a file in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Say I have some arbitrary multi-line text file:

```
sometext
moretext
lastline
```

How can I remove only the last character (the e, not the newline or null) of the file without making the text file invalid?

Comment: What you have done to solve this? -1

Comment: Listing a bunch of garbage sed and awk commands that strip the last character off of every line didn't feel terribly constructive. Heh, knew I was going to get dinged for that one. Still, couldn't bring myself to leave in the sentence "I tried a bunch of sed and awk, but could only strip out every line's last char in a variety of ways".

Answer (score 133, accepted):

A simpler approach (*outputs to stdout*, doesn't update the input file):

```
sed '$ s/.$//' somefile
```

- `$` is a Sed address that matches the last input line only, thus causing the following function call (`s/.$//`) to be executed on the last line only.
- `s/.$//` replaces the last character on the (in this case *last*) line with an empty string; i.e., effectively removes the last char. (before the newline) on the line.

  - Note: The command is a *no-op* if the file ends in *two or more* newlines.

<sup>`.` matches any character on the line, and following it with `$` anchors the match to the end of the line; note how the use of `$` in this *regular expression* is conceptually related, but technically distinct from the previous use of `$` as a Sed *address*.</sup>

- Example with stdin input (assumes Bash, Ksh, or Zsh):

  ```
    $ sed '$ s/.$//' <<< $'line one\nline two'
    line one
    line tw
  ```

To *update the input file* too (do not use if the input file is a symlink):

```
sed -i '$ s/.$//' somefile
```

<sup>Note:</sup>

- On macOS, you'd have to use `-i ''` instead of just `-i`; for an overview of the pitfalls associated with `-i`, see the bottom half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375).
- If you need to process very large input files and/or performance / disk usage are a concern *and* you're using *GNU* utilities (Linux), see [ImHere's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568723/45375).

Comment: @curiousity, no, but fails if there are _two or more_ newlines at the end of the file; I've updated the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 85):

**`truncate`**

```
truncate -s-1 file
```

Removes one (-1) character from the end of the same file. Exactly as a `>>` will append to the same file.

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't retain a trailing newline if it existed.

The solution is:

```
if     [ -n "$(tail -c1 file)" ]    # if the file has not a trailing new line.
then
       truncate -s-1 file           # remove one char as the question request.
else
       truncate -s-2 file           # remove the last two characters
       echo "" >> file              # add the trailing new line back
fi
```

This works because tail takes the last byte (not char).

It takes almost no time even with big files.

**Why not `sed`**

The problem with a sed solution like `sed '$ s/.$//' file` is that it reads the whole file first (taking a long time with large files), then you need a temporary file (of the same size as the original):

```
sed '$ s/.$//' file  > tempfile
rm file; mv tempfile file
```

And then move the tempfile to replace the file.

Comment: On Mac you should `brew install truncate` first and then `truncate -s -1 file`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another using `ex`, which I find not as cryptic as the sed solution:

```
 printf '%s\n' '$' 's/.$//' wq | ex somefile
```

The `$` goes to the last line, the `s` deletes the last character, and `wq` is the well known (to vi users) write+quit.

Answer (score 2):

After a whole bunch of playing around with different strategies (and avoiding sed -i or perl), the best way i found to do this was with:

```
sed '$! { P; D; }; s/.$//' somefile
```

Comment: Not sure why you avoid `sed -i`.  This is just a function to write data back to the file.  Now you only get output to monitor.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to remove the last character in the last line, this `awk` should do:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<NR;i++) print a[i];sub(/.$/,"",a[NR]);print a[NR]}' file
sometext
moretext
lastlin
```

It store all data into an array, then print it out and change last line.

Comment: I didn't have luck trying to > to the same file.  Would recommend outputting to new file, deleting old file, then doing a filename change if necessary.

Comment: @MayTheSForceBeWithYou Gnu Awk 4.1 and newer has inline edit, so try `awk -i 'your code' file`

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark: sed will temporarily remove the file.
So if you are tailing the file, you'll get a "No such file or directory" warning until you reissue the tail command.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**

I created a script and put your text inside on my Desktop. this test file is saved as "old_file.txt"

```
sometext
moretext
lastline
```

Afterwards I wrote a  small script to take the old file and eliminate the **last character in the last line**

```
#!/bin/bash
no_of_new_line_characters=`wc  '/root/Desktop/old_file.txt'|cut -d ' ' -f2`
let "no_of_lines=no_of_new_line_characters+1"
sed -n 1,"$no_of_new_line_characters"p  '/root/Desktop/old_file.txt' > '/root/Desktop/my_new_file'
sed -n "$no_of_lines","$no_of_lines"p '/root/Desktop/old_file.txt'|sed 's/.$//g' >> '/root/Desktop/my_new_file'
```

opening the new_file I created, showed the output as follows:

```
sometext
moretext
lastlin
```

I apologize for my previous answer (wasn't reading carefully)

Comment: It's asking to remove only the last char of a file, not the last char of each line.

Comment: I apologize for my answer wasn't reading carefully..I was able to get the solution using a small script I created. Hope this helps  MaxPRafferty

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/.$//' filename | tee newFilename`

This should do your job.

Comment: That will remove the last character from every line, not just the last character of the last line.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty my bad. I thought the question was to remove the last character of every line

Answer (score 0):

A couple perl solutions, for comparison/reference:

`(echo 1a; echo 2b) | perl -e '$_=join("",<>); s/.$//; print'`

`(echo 1a; echo 2b) | perl -e 'while(<>){ if(eof) {s/.$//}; print }'`

I find the first read-whole-file-into-memory approach can be generally quite useful (less so for this particular problem). You can now do regex's which span multiple lines, for example to combine every 3 lines of a certain format into 1 summary line.

For this problem, `truncate` would be faster and the `sed` version is shorter to type. Note that `truncate` requires a file to operate on, not a stream. Normally I find `sed` to lack the power of perl and I much prefer the extended-regex / perl-regex syntax. But this problem has a nice `sed` solution.