# Change last record separator with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input file as below:

```
apple 6
banana 7
goat 8
```

and I need output as

```
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
```

However, when I run the awk as below, it is printing extra last comma (,). How to avoid that last comma ?

```
awk '{print "{"$2","$1"},"}' data
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat},
```

**Update**:

Actually, I needed output like this

```
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
```

and when I run

```
awk '{print "{"$2","$1"},"}' END {print "\t\t]\n}' data
```

it gives me

```
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}, 
]
```

I don't need the last comma... How to it avoid in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the last character of a file in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305177/how-can-i-remove-the-last-character-of-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 3):

Using `printf` and delayed printf of the comma:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s{%s,%s}",(NR==1?"":"," ORS),$2,$1} END{print ORS "]"}' file
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about piping it to `sed` with the following command line ?

```
awk ... | sed '$ s/,$//'
```

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: No, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

here is one alternative

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{n=NR; next} {print "{" $2 "," $1 "}" (FNR==n?"\n]":",")}' file{,}

{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delay the output:

```
awk 'NR>1{print lastline} {lastline="{" $2 "," $1 "},"; } END{print substr(lastline, 1, length(lastline)-1)}' data
```

each line print last line's output, at the end strip last comma and print it.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=",\n"} {if (NR>1) {print prev} prev="{"$2","$1"}"} END{ORS=""; print prev}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perl solution

```
/tmp> cat media.txt
apple 6
banana 7
goat 8
/tmp> perl -lne ' s/(\S+) (\d+)/{$2,$1}/g; if(eof) { print "$_\n]" } else { print "$_," } ' media.txt
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
/tmp>
```

Or

```
$ perl -lne ' s/(\S+) (\d+)/{$2,$1}/g; print eof ? "$_\n]" : "$_," ' media.txt
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
```

If your file can fit into memory, the below Perl solution would work

```
/tmp> perl -0777 -ne ' s/(\S+) (\d+)/{$2,$1}/g ; print join(",\n",split)."\n]\n" ' media.txt
{6,apple},
{7,banana},
{8,goat}
]
/tmp>
```